# Applying SCD on Talend MDM Server

Tags: h2, talend, change-data-capture

I am using Talend Open Studio for MDM and I have a requirement to do version control on customer records.

When using an Oracle database, I can use tOracleSCD to capture the changes. Likewise, for MySQL, I can use tMysqlSCD.

But in Talend Open Studio for MDM, the only supported database is H2 and so I am storing all master records in a H2 database.

In this case, how can I achieve version control as there is no component available in Talend
for H2 database?

Answer (score 1):

The SCD components just set up triggers on the watched tables and provide an easy interface into reading the trigger output tables.

You could set the triggers up manually on the H2 database by recreating the database in MySQL and then using the MySQL SCD components to work out what it's doing and work out how to read the data back in and then recreate those steps with H2 components as part of a data integration task.

That said, Talend MDM has the concept of a journal which stores all of the changes made to a data record. The [Talend Open Studio for MDM documentation](https://help.talend.com/display/HOME/Talend+Open+Studio+for+MDM) has some more detailed information about [how to view the journal](https://help.talend.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=19428908). All changes made through the MDM interface should make an entry in the journal automatically.